# How to connect to database dynamic and secure?

Tags: asp.net

I want to connect to the database dynamically.for each client we have separate databases.
I have one master database.from master database I get Servername,database name,user id,password feilds according to client login.
Now using this information I form a connection string which will connect to the correct database.
Every time(when connection required) connect to master db and get details then form a connection string is time consuming.
So once Servername,database name,user id,password feilds i get or connection 
string is get form I want to keep it in session which should be secure.
How I can manage that?

Comment: session will be fine, it is not more or less secure than storing the credentials in the master database

Comment: but session may hack....

Comment: session is stored on your server in the memory and is a bit more secure than storing credentials in db as you are doing, so unless evil hacker already is on your server the sessions is ok , and I mean session object on the server , not setting them in a cookie on the client.